# Migrate Qlik reports to azure

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, qlikview, qliksense

I did some research and found that there are some options to migrate on-premises QlikView reports to Azure data lake , using the IaaS approach.

Is there an PaaS component for QlikView in Azure ?

Comment: hi,any updates here? Any further i can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today , there is no PaaS component in Azure for QlikView .  We have to go for the IaaS option, while migrating.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any Azure PaaS component to bind Qlik and ADLS, except using REST API from this [link](https://community.qlik.com/t5/Qlik-Sense-Data-Connectivity/QlikSense-connection-to-ADLS/td-p/2166). The details of authentication of REST API could be referred in that case.

Here are some third-party tools to implement the transmission:

1.Dremio: https://www.dremio.com/, which supports [ADLS](https://docs.dremio.com/data-sources/azure-data-lake-store.html) connector.

2.Panoply: https://panoply.io/integrations/azure-blob-storage/, which supports Azure Blob Storage connector. Next step, you could move data from Azure Blob Storage into ADLS with ADF copy activity.